# Неправильная работа decimal

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте

Есть код

```
int start = 2;
int len = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    decimal d = 1 / start;
    Console.WriteLine(@"1/" + start + " = " + d);
    start = start * 2;
}
```

По логике должно быть так

```
1/2 = 0.5
1/4 = 0.25
1/8 = 0.125
...
```

Почему decimal при делении 1 / 2 выводит 0?

Как это исправить?

Comment: потому что у тебя вообще decimal Нет в коде, ну и используешь ты **целочисленное** деление, так как все аргументы - целые числа

Comment: Потому что 1 и 2 целые.

Comment: 1) `double start = 2.0;` или 2) `d = 1.0 / start;`

Comment: Спасибо большое заменил `1` на `1.0d` и все заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: `d` - это double, если ты хочешь `decimal` - ставь [`m`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal): `decimal d = 1m / start;`

Answer (score 4):

У вас деление двух целочисленных типов дает целочисленный результат. Измените свой код на такой: `decimal d = (decimal)1 / start;`

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас зачту ответ

Comment: Зачем создавать int, а потом приводить к decimal `(decimal)1` ?? Можно же сразу сказать, что 1 -- это decimal, например `var d = 1m / start;`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk на месте единицы могла быть переменная, я дал универсальный ответ. Варианты с указанием типа есть в комментариях к вопросу

Comment: oops, не заметил :)